# w3c validator checks cached version of site

Tags: javascript, html

[Here](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsayanchaga.com%2F&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

last error is Error Line 420, Column 42: Stray start tag script.

```
<script src="/skin/sayan_health/js/nc.js"></script>
```

But I fixed this error placing script tag inside body tag
and if I go directly to the site *http://sayanchaga.com* in web inspector I see that its placed rightly. So why w3c validator still uses cached version of site and shows me that error again?

Comment: You can use the direct input to paste your view source to validate on the fly. http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options

Comment: The error is till there. Your `<script>` tag is outside the `<html>`. BTW to make sure the validator doesn't use cached version you could paste your url with `home.php?foo=1234` (some random query variables).

Comment: `<script src="/skin/sayan_health/js/nc.js"></script>` is out side of the closing `</html>`

Comment: Also why have you disabled right clicking on your website?

Answer (score 1):

The web inspector does not show you the source code. It shows you a representation of the DOM.

The browser performs normalisation and error correction on your code when it constructs the DOM so the DOM does not accurately reflect your source code.

Use View Source instead.

The `<script>` tag is still in the wrong place when I look at the site.

Comment: There is an element of truth to this but W3 validator does also cache results.

Comment: @AshleyMedway — That seems very unlikely. It's a tool designed to help people find errors, it would be remarkably difficult to test changes if it insisted on using cached results.

Comment: @AshleyMedway — The phrase "There is an element of truth to this" implies that there is something which isn't true about my answer. What is that?

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain properly, If you have output caching enabled on the website then the validator holds on to the result. In output caching you need to ignore useragent `W3C_Validator/1.3`. The element of truth is that the markup is actually still incorrect as you point out. However it is possible to have W3 cache your page result.

Comment: Output caching is when *your server* caches the results of running server side code. That has nothing to do with the Validator. The Validator isn't caching anything, it is just getting the same data from the server each time it asks for it.